# Blur half a page

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to blur the content of half a page, basically I need to show a document preview before the customer pays for it.

In order to accomplish that I have a HTML page which looks pretty much like this:
[image]

I need to apply a blur, the blur should start from the 50% of the page height, then I will take an screenshot and show that image to the customer.

So:

1. I can't apply the filter blur to a `div` because there are many divs involved. Lets say that the blur will start from somewhere around "Where does it come from"
2. I tried to add a `div` position absolute with a filter blur, but the blur is not being applied over the text. I also tried to do that with SVGs but no joy.

Ideas?

Comment: Why aren't you just applying the blur effect to the screenshot?

Comment: @JosephSible that's my last resource, I want it to be maintained by the front end team, so maybe one SO friend knows a trick.

Comment: Not much help, but shouldn't you be able to just style the div you want to blur and than unblur depending user action?

Comment: @PHClaus the thing is that I have to blur half a div

Comment: half a div of many divs??? whats wrong with id or class, or just read the file into a  buffer, get its size, return half of it, then do your thing and send the rest when ready...

Comment: @PHClaus I don't need workarounds, I have workarounds, I want to know if someone knows how to blur half a page using HTML CSS and/or SVGs, DIVs overlays, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that may be a bit rickety, but works - in Firefox, at least:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg width="600" height="800" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <filter id="halfBlur" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0.5" width="1" height="0.5">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
  </filter>
  <g id="source">
    <foreignObject width="600" height="800">
      <html:iframe style="width:600px;height:800px" src=""></html:iframe>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#source" filter="url(#halfBlur)"/>
</svg>
```

Mark that the `<use>` element only works if it references an SVG container element, but not the `<foreignObject>` directly.

Care must be taken to make all elements big enough to contain the complete html page. As an extra measure, it might be a good idea to provide the `html` element of the embeded page with a `overflow:hidden` rule. If scrollbars show up, they will work on both halfs of the page independently.

Comment: Should I get a page with only that svg, and set in the iframe `src` the html path? or should I include this in the existing html? I can't find any doc related to "html:iframe"

Comment: Set the iframe `src` to your html page. The `html:iframe` syntax is a XML namespace syntax, see the namespace definition for `xmlns:html` in the svg element

Comment: Works in only Firefox, as you said, it's not working in Chrome :/, thanks a lot for you time man.